# How to Add AndroidAuto to Linux Headunit

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, android-auto

I am developing a Linux based multimedia and my question is, how can I add support for AndroidAuto to my system?

Currently, I have found a github source code from f1xpl, but it's not official. I couldn't find anything in Android's Documents. Does anybody knows what's the official solution for Adding AndroidAuto Support to Linux based multimedia? what need's to be done?